# When using tcpdump's `-i any` argument, how to get also interface name inline?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcpdump

I'm diagnosing some networking issues with an inordinate amount of network interfaces on a Linux server.

I'm needing to dump all interface traffic as per `tcpdump -i any`, but I'm not finding any definition of the interface identifier (eth0, eth10, br4, etc.)

Is there a way to instruct `tcpdump` to include interface info with each packet per line?

Comment: I think this might answer your question, https://serverfault.com/questions/224698/how-to-display-interface-in-tcpdump-output-flow

Comment: Thanks guys. I've giving a little more concise answer below based on that @Desultory.

Answer (score 2):

*It turns out that this was essentially a duplicate that I was unable to find easily and the system didn't recommend.  I thought I should give the answer here since it may not be 100% clear from the linked suggestion in the comment(s).*

*First, [this](https://serverfault.com/a/660350/101375) contains the answer more-or-less, but you have to go to his German [website](http://sebastianhaas.de/anydump-release/) to get a more up-to-date script. Further a simple copy and paste can present difficulties depending on your browser, etc.*

---

### **ANSWER**

What you will want to do is to **use this script** (version 1.3): [`dump.sh`](https://cl.ly/3G1f2H3M3U0p/dump.sh)

It can be executed via: `dump.sh [-i interface] [tcpdump-parameters]`

For example, I was hunting for "incorrect" flags in a sizeable XenServer installation that were due to incorrect offloading attempts by the operating system.  I was able to use the command with piping thus:

```
./dump.sh -v -nn | grep -i incorrect | egrep --line-buffered -v "Interface:lo:|eth3|vif21.4|xenbr4"
```

Comment: With this (for me) packets are not being displayed in order (based on time).